# Error when adding image target to Vuforia Web API using PHP

Tags: php, laravel, api, vuforia, vuforia-cloud-recognition

I am trying to add an image target to the Vuforia Web API using PHP and Laravel. I have followed the Vuforia Web API documentation and implemented the authentication process as described. However, when I make the API request to add the image target, I receive the following error:

Error:

> {"result_code":"Fail","transaction_id":"5e5f2b5e8e624c2d8e5f2b5e8e622f6d","result_string":"Bad
> Request - Invalid Content-MD5 header"}

I have double-checked my implementation, and I believe I am calculating the Content-MD5 hash correctly based on the raw request body. Here is a snippet of my code for generating the request headers and signing the request:

```php
 public function addTarget(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'width' => 'required|numeric',
            'image' => [
                'required',
                'file',
                'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
                'max:2048',
                'dimensions:min_width=320',
            ],
            'animation_name' => 'required|string',
            'audio_name' => 'required|string',
            'video_name' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    
        $client = new Client();
    
        $imageFile = $request->file('image')->getPathname();
        $imageEncoded = base64_encode(file_get_contents($imageFile));
    
        // Create metadata JSON object
        $metadata = [
            'animation_name' => $request->input('animation_name'),
            'audio_name' => $request->input('audio_name'),
            'video_name' => $request->input('video_name'),
        ];
        $metadataJson = json_encode($metadata);
        $metadataEncoded = base64_encode($metadataJson);
    
        $requestBody = [
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'width' => $request->input('width'),
            'image' => $imageEncoded,
            'application_metadata' => $metadataEncoded
        ];

        $requestBodyRaw = json_encode($requestBody);
    
        $url = 'https://vws.vuforia.com/targets';
        $headers = $this->getHeaders($requestBody);
    
        \Log::debug('Request body: ' . json_encode($requestBody));
        \Log::debug('Headers: ' . json_encode($headers));
        \Log::debug('String to sign: ' . $this->getStringToSign($requestBody));
        


        try {
            $response = $client->post($url, [
                'body' => $requestBodyRaw,
                'headers' => $headers,
                'verify' => config('services.curl_cainfo'),
            ]);
            
    
            $result = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
    
            // Store the image in the local storage
            $imageName = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
            $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/images', $imageName);
            $imagePath = 'storage/images/' . $imageName;
    
            // Save the image and metadata in the PostgreSQL database
            $imageTarget = new imageTarget();
            $imageTarget->name = $request->input('name');
            $imageTarget->width = $request->input('width');
            $imageTarget->image_path = $imagePath;
            $imageTarget->metadata = $metadataJson;
            $imageTarget->save();
    
            return view('success', ['result' => $result]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return view('error', ['message' => $e->getMessage()]);
        }
    }
    

    private function getHeaders($requestBody)
    {
        $serverAccessKey = '7970dca2f5f6d6e8c577a41eaf17aff759f1d94b';
        $serverSecretKey = '6c30fd48028cd24caebc52d0761b4b121bcc6cc0';
    
        $date = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT';
        $method = 'POST';
        $path = '/targets';
    
        $requestBodyRaw = json_encode($requestBody);
        $contentMD5 = base64_encode(md5($requestBodyRaw, true));
        $contentType = 'application/json';
    
        $stringToSign = "{$method}\n{$contentMD5}\n{$contentType}\n{$date}\n{$path}";
        $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $stringToSign, $serverSecretKey, true));
    
        return [
            'Host' => 'vws.vuforia.com',
            'Date' => $date,
            'Content-Type' => $contentType,
            'Authorization' => "VWS {$serverAccessKey}:{$signature}"
        ];
    }

    private function getStringToSign($requestBody)
{
    $date = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT';
    $method = 'POST';
    $path = '/targets';

    $requestBodyRaw = json_encode($requestBody);
    $contentMD5 = base64_encode(md5($requestBodyRaw, true));

    $contentType = 'application/json';

    return "{$method}\n{$contentMD5}\n{$contentType}\n{$date}\n{$path}";
}
```

I have tried several adjustments to my code, but I still receive the same error. I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions from anyone who has encountered a similar issue or knows how to resolve it.

Thank you.

I followed the Vuforia Web API documentation to implement adding an image target using PHP and Laravel. I expected to successfully add an image target and receive a response from the API with a result_code of "Success" and a transaction_id.

Here are the steps I took:

I created a new Laravel project and set up a route to handle the image target submission.
I implemented the authentication process as described in the Vuforia Web API documentation, using the server access key and server secret key.
I created a function to handle the request, validate the input, and generate the request body, including the image and metadata.
I implemented the calculation of the Content-MD5 hash based on the raw request body, as well as the creation of the signature for the Authorization header.
I sent the API request using Guzzle HTTP Client with the generated headers and request body.
However, I received the following error:

> Error:
> {"result_code":"Fail","transaction_id":"5e5f2b5e8e624c2d8e5f2b5e8e622f6d","result_string":"Bad
> Request - Invalid Content-MD5 header"}

Despite multiple attempts to troubleshoot and adjust my implementation, I continue to encounter this error. I have reviewed the relevant sections of the Vuforia Web API documentation and made sure to follow the steps provided.

I would appreciate any suggestions or insights on how to resolve this issue and successfully add an image target using the Vuforia Web API.

Comment: Your getHeaders function doesn't return the calculated MD5 content. Make it work inside your original function first, then split it out in your private functions